# redirect to the product url from observer or controller magento 2

Tags: magento2, event-observer, product-urls, redirection

> i want to redirect from observer to the default magento product url from observer.

```
public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory
        ) {

              $this->_responseFactory = $responseFactory;
        }

        public function execute(Observer $observer) {

                $productUrl = $currentProduct->getProductUrl(); 
                //$RedirectUrl= $this->_url->getUrl('chennaievent\index\index');
                return $this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($productUrl)->sendResponse();

            }


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
<?php
namespace Company\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Test implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $resultRedirect;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
        ResultFactory $result
    ) {
        $this->_responseFactory = $responseFactory;
        $this->resultRedirect = $result;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer) 
    {
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirect->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        //$resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
        $productUrl = $currentProduct->getProductUrl(); 
        $resultRedirect->setUrl($productUrl);
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
}
```

Comment: sir,its not working

Comment: i am trying this link https://magecomp.com/blog/redirect-category-with-single-product-to-product-page-in-magento-2/ but its just reloading the page but not redirecting to product page

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly you are looking for but as per magecomp url you have given, you may apply following solution.

File: etc\frontend\di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View">
        <plugin name="redirect_single_category_product" type="[Vendor]\[Module]\Plugin\CategoryView" sortOrder="10" />
    </type>
</config>
```

File: Plugin\CategoryView.php

```
<?php

namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Plugin;

class CategoryView
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface $response,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFactory $actionFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository
    )
    {
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_response = $response;
        $this->actionFactory = $actionFactory;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }

    public function afterExecute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View $subject,
        $result
    )
    {
        // replace your condition here
        if(1)
        {
            // for example take first product
            $productId = 1;
            $current_product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId, false, $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId());

            $this->_response->setRedirect($current_product->getProductUrl());
            $this->request->setDispatched(true);
            return $this->actionFactory->create('Magento\Framework\App\Action\Redirect');
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

This should work. Replace [Vendor], [Module] with your vendor and module name.
Let me know if you are looking for something else or specific.

Comment: After applying this, if you goto any category page, it will redirect to product page with product id 1.

Comment: ,no its not working means its not redirecting to the product details page

Comment: Put a die('here'); inside if(1) statement and see if it is executing it or not. If not then probably you need to flush cache. Let me know the output of it.